# Microsoft Word font versions not compatible

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts

My wife uses the Britannic Bold font to print some labels. She cannot print them on my computer because mine does not have the same font.

She is using Word 2010, which has version 1.1 of the font, and I am using Word 2013, which has font version 1.5.

The version is the only obvious difference.  Is there a workaround, or a way to match the versions between the two computers?

Comment: You can copy the font file across from her PC to yours.

Answer (score 3):

When saving the document, go to Save Options and check the `Embed Fonts in the file`, it will allow you to edit the documents in your PC too, but not exporting the font.